# Shared folder issues on Dropbox

Tags: permissions, dropbox, file-sharing

User 'example@gmail.com' is owner of many folders which are shared with me (& others).

When I update some files in those folders, the owner is not getting the updates in his/her account/folders.

A strange scenario is that, when the folder owner checked the folders shared with me, are showing as normal (unshared) folders. I've tried sharing the owner (he/she is showing as the current owner in the shared folder option) again, owner got the share invitation. Once accepted, it listed in the files of the owner and appeared as "folder name (1)" (as duplicate?) in the root location.

This assumed to be a bug from Dropbox. Also assume that this happened after the user (example@gmail.com) upgraded the account to 100GB package.

Would like to get this issue resolved as the owner is not able to view the changes done on the folders. Could it be a 'mapping' bug from dropbox's end?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you log into the website for the user example@gmail.com, what files and folders show there?

Comment: This sounds like something for Dropbox support.

Comment: @cathoo It shows the old folders/files user had and the folder I shared ("folder name (1)")

Comment: @SilverlightFox Seem that DB support is very poor. They don't respond! :(

Comment: Try https://forums.dropbox.com/